# How to and use variables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SetGems (p_requestid int, p_akcija int)

BEGIN

if(p_akcija=0)
then

declare v_userId int;
declare v_vingems decimal;

SELECT r.user_id INTO v_userId FROM Requests r WHERE r.Id=p_requestid;


end
$$
delimiter;
```

/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare v_userId int;
declare v_vingems decimal;
SELECT r.user_id INTO v_u' at line 8 */

Don't know where the problem is...

Comment: Try to declare you variables right after `BEGIN`. And you need `END IF;`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Did that, same thing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
First declare all the variables than use if condition like this:
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SetGems (p_requestid int, p_akcija int)
BEGIN
declare v_userId int;
declare v_vingems decimal;
if(p_akcija=0) then
SELECT r.user_id INTO v_userId FROM Requests r WHERE r.Id=p_requestid;
end
$$
delimiter;
```

Comment: there is still an error /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4 */